# How could a class in a package use another version of an object type?

Tags: java

I need to create a Java Project containing two packages: `com.myPackage` and `com.myPackage.subpackage`.

The two packages contain the following classes:

```
/* **************************************** */
package com.myPackage.subpackage;

public class ClassA {
      public ClassB cB = new ClassB();  // Here I need to have NewClassB instead of ClassB
      // ...
}

public class ClassB extends ClassC {
    public void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}

/* **************************************** */
package com.myPackage;

public class NewClassB extends ClassC {
    public void doSomethingElse() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My problem is: I'd like to keep the `subpackage` "multi purpose" (not related to the special case of the application I'm building now) so I can re-use it in the future. But in my application I also need that `ClassA` uses `NewClassB` instead of `ClassB`, in the definition of object `cB`: how can I do this?
I thought that I could create `ClassB` as an Interface and then implement it in `NewClassB`.. but then I couldn't instantiate the object `cB` in `ClassA`, since it would be an interface.
Also, `ClassB` and `NewClassB` must extend another class (`ClassC`).

Could anyone provide suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
For clarity, I don't want `NewClassB` to be named or defined anywhere in the `subpackage`.
Also, I cannot define a `NewClassA` which uses `NewClassB`, because in my actual application the `NewClassA` is in turn used by other classes, then I would end up in doing the `New` version of all of them...

Comment: If you want a `NewClassB`, then make one. You're constructing a `ClassB` and getting a `ClassB` as a result. I don't understand what you're expecting to happen

Comment: Thanks Silvio, I explain: I made a ```NewClassB```, but I don't want to make it in the same package of ```ClassA``` (which must not have any explicit reference to ```NewClassB```). Then how can I have ```ClassA``` to use ```NewClassB``` ?

Comment: @user14520608 Can you provide the `ClassB` instance as a parameter for the constructor of `ClassA` and save it that way in `cB`? (Keyword: dependency injection)

Comment: @Progman : I think that doesn't work, because even if I pass ```cB``` as a parameter I must define its type, and ```ClassB``` is a different type than ```NewClassB```...

Comment: @user14520608 Use a new interface or `ClassC` as the type for the new constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You always instantiate exactly the class you want (which, if you think about it, makes sense, how else is the JVM supposed to know which specific subclass you want right now?)

It sounds like you want `NewClassB` to extend `ClassB`.

```java
public class NewClassB extends ClassB {...}
```

then you can use it as

```java
public class ClassA {
      public ClassB cB = new NewClassB();  
}
```

Because of inheritance, it's absolutely fine to assign an instance of `NewClassB` to a `ClassB` typed variable, or even to a `ClassC` typed variable in this case (since `ClassB` extends `ClassC`).

If you instead want `ClassA` not to have any knowledge of the concrete implementation of `ClassB`, you can simply pass it along in the constructor:

```java
public class ClassA {
    public ClassB cB;

    public ClassA(ClassB cB){
        this.cB = cB;
    }
}
```

Does this help your problem?

Comment: Thanks, that was very instructive! Yes, my point is that I don't want ```NewClassB``` to be written anywhere in the ```subpackage``` (so I can use it for other purposes in the future). Then your solution n.2 seems interesting. Will I be able to pass ```cB``` as ```ClassB``` even if it's actually a ```NewClassB```? Thanks

Comment: @user14520608 If `NewClassB` is of type `ClassB` (aka extends `ClassB`), then yes. As an example, if you have two classes `Apple` and `Pear` which both extend the class `Fruit`, and you have a method which expects a parameter of the type `Fruit`, then you will be able to pass either of them (or any other further sub-class you define).

Comment: @user14520608 If you want to detach some of your code from the actual implementation, the usual approach is to have an interface define the methods you need, and use parameters / variables of that interface type. That means that you will be able to handle any class that implements that interface, either directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be able to extend class A into NewClassA, and make NewClassB extend ClassB (which means it transitively extends ClassC too). Then override the constructor for NewClassA to assign `cB = new NewClassB()`, which is legal because NewClassB is still, also, a ClassB.

You could also make ClassB and abstract class (rather than an interface), and then you can have a static factory method that constructs and returns a concrete implementation (ClassBImpl), but also have a different version (ClassBNewImpl) for your special use case, in which case both ClassBImpl and ClassBNewImpl extend ClassB (abstract), which itself extends ClassC, but in this way neither ClassBImpl directly extends the other.

Comment: Thank you, your solution #2 is interesting.